# Cannot get selected value from SelectList Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages, selectlist

I'm making a simple MovieApp using `Razor Pages`. I have two models: **Movie** `* - 1` **Genre**. What I want is that when I navigate to **Genres** page and select a particular Genre, I want to show **List** of all the movies associated with this Genre, and I would like to be able to select and **Navigate** to the **Movie** from **Genre**.

The problem that I have is that the Razor Pages' **SelectList** is not Binding selected *reference* value (i.e objects of Movies) from the list, but when I have `IDs` of **Movies** instead, I'm getting the selected value correctly.

Here is my code:

**Details.cshtml**

```
<div>
<h4>Genre</h4>
<hr />
<form method="post">
    <dl class="row">
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Genre.GenreTitle)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Genre.GenreTitle)
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <div class="form-group" style="width: 250px;">
        <label asp-for="MoviesSL" class="control-label"></label>
        <select asp-for="SelectedMovie" class="form-control"
                asp-items="Model.MoviesSL">
        </select>
    </div>
    <span asp-validation-for="SelectedMovie.ID" class="text-danger"></span>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Navigate" class="btn btn-info" />
    </div>
</form>
```

**Details.cshtml.cs**

```
    public Genre Genre { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Movies list")]
    public SelectList MoviesSL { get; set; }
    private Movie selectedMovie;
    [BindProperty]
    public Movie SelectedMovie 
    {
        get => selectedMovie;
        set
        {
            selectedMovie = value;
            //int g = 0;
        }
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        Genre = await _context.Genre.Include(m => m.Movies).FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.GenreId == id);
        MoviesSL = new SelectList(Genre.Movies);

        //int g = 0;

        if (Genre == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Page();
    }

    public void OnPost()
    {
        var k = SelectedMovie;

        //int g = 0;
    }
```

**Movie.cs**

```
public class Movie
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Display(Name = "Release Date")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

        [Range(1, 300)]
        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(5)]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9""'\s-]*$")]
        public string Rating { get; set; }

        public int GenreId { get; set; }
        public Genre Genre { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Title;
        }
    }
```

**Genre.cs**

```
public class Genre
{
    public Genre()
    {
        Movies = new List<Movie>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int GenreId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 5)]
    [Display(Name = "Genre Title")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z]*$")]
    public string GenreTitle { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Number of movies")]
    public ICollection<Movie> Movies { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return GenreTitle;
    }
}
```

When I select a movie from the list and try to *"navigate"* through the post method I get an empty **Movie** object.

[image: When I select a movie from the list, I get an empty Movie object]

However, when I have **SelectList** of `IDs` instead `Movies`, it works properly:

[image: Working correctly]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly,`<select></select>` will only return it's selected value,it cannot bind model.And you can use `MoviesSL = new  SelectList(Genre.Movies,"ID","Title");` as `Sergey` said.And then you can return the selected ID of Movie to post handler.And then get Movie with ID from _context.

1.remove

```
<span asp-validation-for="SelectedMovie.ID" class="text-danger"></span>
```

2.change

```
[BindProperty]
    public Movie SelectedMovie 
    {
        get => selectedMovie;
        set
        {
            selectedMovie = value;
            //int g = 0;
        }
    }
```

to

```
[BindProperty]
        public int SelectedMovie { get; set; }
```

3.change

```
public void OnPost()
    {
        var k = SelectedMovie;

        //int g = 0;
    }
```

to

```
public void OnPost()
    {
        Movie k = _context.Movie.Where(m=>m.ID== SelectedMovie).FirstOrDefault();

        //int g = 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To initiate SelectList you need 3 properties: list of items, name of property  of the item that can be used a Value for the  SelectList, and name that can be used to display SelectList.

So you have to fix SelectList code:

```
 MoviesSL = new  SelectList(Genre.Movies,"ID","Title");
```

Comment: It's not working either, strangely the `post form` is sending the `ID` of **Genre** and no other details of any **Movie**.

Comment: It is case sensitive. I don't know your Movie properties names.  Try 'ID" and what you use in Moview instead of "Name"

Comment: I understand that I should put my own properties here, but as I said, the selected item is not being returned when my `SelectList` consists of `Movies`, instead, it returns only the `Id` of `Genre` which is weird because it is not requested anywhere.

Comment: Could you post your movie class pls?

Comment: Well, as I mentioned above, it's not about **instantiating the SelectList**, but rather there should be some other usage of it which I'm not aware of. When I'm choosing a `Movie` from the list and `post` this object, what I get is just an empty object, and it's `ID` is equal to its **GenreId**. But when I have a `SelectList` of `Movie.ID`, then it is working totally fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230772/discussion-between-miraziz-and-sergey).